# how to insert/update an entity attribute that is annotated as @CreationTimestamp?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="transactions")
    @NamedQuery(name="Transaction.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Transaction t")
    public class Transaction implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=11)
        private int id;


        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(name="created_at")
        private Date createdAt;
}
```

I have above entity using with Hibernate. I have a requirement where I need to update createdAt field but when I try following it didn't work. The createdAt is from the date of creations, which make sense.

```
Transaction newTransaction = new Transaction();
newTransaction.setCreatedAT(new Date);    
sessionFactory.openSession().save(newTransaction);
```

Is there a way to keep @CreationTimestamp annotation and be able to modify or set another date when needed ?

**I am using Hibernate 4 with Spring. Any solution or another suggestion will be highly appreciated **

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to set it manually? Much cleaner solution would be to have 2 methods in your entity class. Both annotations are from the persistence package.

```
private Date creationTime;
private Date modificationTime;

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    Date now = Date();
    this.creationTime = now;
    this.modificationTime = now;
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
    this.modificationTime = Date();
}
```

Or preferably use Java 8/Jodatime classes, in which case you need set `@Type` for fields manually as Hibernate doesn't support them out of the box as far as I know.

Comment: I don't see how this is much cleaner then using  @CreationTimestamp. The question is not about why I need to manually set it. I am just asking if that is possible - thanks!

Comment: Not a valid design when trying to modify something that is supposed to be set only once (createdDate) by the library. I assume the annotations overwrite any value that is currently present so you can't do that. I would never imagine a reason for why it needs to be changed. If you really need that kind of functionality then don't define the annotation at all and just use getters/setters.

Comment: @Vaelyr One reason I could think of is a Restore-Backup / Import/export Feature at the application level. Let's say you allow to export and import data and you want the import to "override" the values exactly as they were in the database before including the created column. But during normal usage you want the fields to be set by the annotations.